# Store huge amount of data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

```
create table article
(
     ArticleID int constraint cnst-name Primary key,
     Description datatype
)
```

I am creating this table in SQL Server 2014. I am trying to create a table where I can store articles with huge data (it can be 1000-2000 words article description). I don't know which data type to choose for description column.

I chose `varchar(max)` but there is a limitation that each row has to be <= 900 bytes. Please guide me if my table structure is right.

Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: `varchar(max)` has limitation of `2GB` data not `900 Bytes`. I would say just go with `Varchar(max)` or maybe `Varchar(8000)` ??

Comment: `varchar(max)` should be fine, it should be more than enough to handle the data. You could use `text` but that will depreciated in future versions of msssql, not sure about mysql though

Comment: 900 bytes is the maximum size for index keys

Comment: If I take varchar(1000) I get these error message while creating the table "Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index 'UQ__MOVIE__FBF8DE943C0FC396' has maximum length of 2000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail." when I try to add data in the table I get the error

Comment: when I try to add data in the table I get the error: Error Source: .Net sqlClient Data Provider. Error Message: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `nvarchar(max)`. Unlike `varchar` is supports unicode. The limit 2GB should be enough.

The limit of row size is 8060B, so You can not store more than about 4000 unicode characters in the row. But the restriction does not apply here, because `nvarchar(max)` is not stored in the row. The row contains pointer only. This one indirection is the price for the "unlimited" size.

Comment: If I use nvarchar(1000) I get error mentioned above in the comments.

Comment: @jvf "900 bytes is the maximum size for index keys" - did You read that? You can not have unique constraint (which is realized by index) with 2kB key due to this limitation.

Comment: I had removed the unique key but still it was giving error, I created new database and now it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `VARCHAR(max)`.
2000 words in a .txt file is around 13kb.
I would not call that 'huge'.